# Problem with Screen Manager in Kivy Python

Tags: python, user-interface, button, kivy, screen

What I want to do is to switch the screen when the "join" button is pressed.
This is what I have written.

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

class ConnectingPage(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.cols = 2

        self.add_widget(Label(text = "Usename:"))
        self.username = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.username)

        self.add_widget(Label(text = "Password:"))
        self.password = TextInput(multiline=False,password = True)
        self.add_widget(self.password)

        self.joinbutton = Button(text="Join")
        self.joinbutton.bind(on_press = self.click_join_button)
        self.add_widget(Label())  
        self.add_widget(self.joinbutton)
        
    def click_join_button(self, instance):
        username = self.username.text
        password = self.password.text
        info = "you can enter"
        MyApp.screen_manager.current = "Info"
            
# Simple information/error page
class InfoPage(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1
        self.message = Label(text = "welcome",halign="center", valign="middle", font_size=30)
        self.add_widget(self.message)

        

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.screen_manager = ScreenManager()
        self.connecting_page = ConnectingPage()
        screen = Screen(name='Connect')
        screen.add_widget(self.connecting_page)

        # Info page
        self.info_page = InfoPage()
        screen = Screen(name='Info')
        screen.add_widget(self.info_page)
        
        return ConnectingPage()

MyApp().run()
```

Everything works fine in the starting but when the button "join" is pressed, this is the error:

AttributeError: type object 'MyApp' has no attribute 'self'

Please suggest what to do next.

Comment: I have only a vague idea of how Kivy works so the full stack trace would be helpful in diagnosing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `build()` method returns `ConnectingPage()`, so your `App` is    not actually using a `ScreenManager`. All the code in that `build()`    method (except that `return`) has no effect. Here is a modified version of your `MyApp` class that actually uses `ScreenManager`:

```
class MyApp(App):
    screen_manager = ScreenManager()  # this make screen_manager a class vaiable

    def build(self):
        # self.screen_manager = ScreenManager()
        self.connecting_page = ConnectingPage()
        screen = Screen(name='Connect')
        screen.add_widget(self.connecting_page)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)  # add screen to ScreenManager

        # Info page
        self.info_page = InfoPage()
        screen = Screen(name='Info')
        screen.add_widget(self.info_page)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)  # add screen to ScreenManager

        # return ConnectingPage()
        return self.screen_manager
```

This allows your code:

```
MyApp.screen_manager.current = "Info"
```

to work, but it is an odd construction.

A more typical construction would be something like this:

```
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        screen_manager = ScreenManager()
        connecting_page = ConnectingPage()
        screen = Screen(name='Connect')
        screen.add_widget(connecting_page)
        screen_manager.add_widget(screen)  # add screen to ScreenManager

        # Info page
        info_page = InfoPage()
        screen = Screen(name='Info')
        screen.add_widget(info_page)
        screen_manager.add_widget(screen)  # add screen to ScreenManager

        # return ConnectingPage()
        return screen_manager  # return the ScreenManager
```

But this requires a change in the code that changes the `Screen`:

```
App.get_running_app().root.current = "Info"
```